# ARM Cortex A7 returning PMCCNTR = 0 in kernel mode, and Illegal instruction in user mode (even after PMUSERENR = 1)

Tags: linux, arm, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I want to read the cycle count register (PMCCNTR) on a Raspberry Pi 2, which has an ARM Cortex A7 core.  I compile a kernel module for it as follows:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module()
{
  volatile u32 PMCR, PMUSERENR, PMCCNTR;

  // READ PMCR
  PMCR = 0xDEADBEEF;
  asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0\n\t" : "=r" (PMCR));
  printk (KERN_INFO "PMCR = %x\n", PMCR);

  // READ PMUSERENR 
  PMUSERENR = 0xDEADBEEF;
  asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0\n\t" : "=r" (PMUSERENR));
  printk (KERN_INFO "PMUSERENR = %x\n", PMUSERENR);

  // WRITE PMUSERENR = 1
  asm volatile ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0\n\t" : : "r" (1));

  // READ PWMUSERENR AGAIN
  asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0\n\t" : "=r" (PMUSERENR));
  printk (KERN_INFO "PMUSERENR = %x\n", PMUSERENR);

  // READ PMCCNTR
  PMCCNTR = 0xDEADBEEF;
  asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0\n\t" : "=r" (PMCCNTR));
  printk (KERN_ALERT "PMCCNTR = %x\n", PMCCNTR);
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

and, after `insmod`, I observe the following in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
PMCR = 41072000
PMUSERENR = 0
PMUSERENR = 1
PMCCNTR = 0
```

When I try to read PMCCNTR from user-mode, I get illegal instruction, even after PMUSERENR has been set to 1.

Why does PMCCNTR read as 0 in kernel mode, and an illegal instruction in user-mode?  Is there something else I need to do that I'm not doing to enable the PMCCNTR?

### Update 1

Partly solved.  The solution to the multi-core issue is to call `on_each_cpu` like so:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static void enable_ccnt_read(void* data)
{
  // WRITE PMUSERENR = 1
  asm volatile ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0\n\t" : : "r" (1));
}

int init_module()
{
  on_each_cpu(enable_ccnt_read, NULL, 1);
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

I can now read PMCCNTR from userland:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned ccnt_read ()
{
  volatile unsigned cc;
  asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r" (cc));
  return cc;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << ccnt_read() << std::endl;
}
```

To run a userland program on a specific core you can use `taskset` like so (example, run on core 2):

```
$ taskset -c 2 ./ccnt_read
0
```

The PMCCNTR are still not incrementing.  They need to be "switched on" somehow.

Comment: Doesn't it have _four_ Cortex-A7 cores? Are you sure the module code and the userspace access have both run on the same one?

Comment: @Notlikethat: Interesting idea, I'm not sure what is shared between cores and what isn't (ie do I need to set PMUSERENR on each of the four cores, or is there one PMUSERENR register shared between all four) - but regardless, that doesn't explain why PMCCNTR is reading as 0 in kernel mode.  ie Even if each core had its own PMCCNTR, you would still expect them all to be non-zero, right?

Comment: @Notlikethat: Actually the multicore nature of the Cortex A-7 is part of what ARM produce.  The L2 Cache for example, is a singelton not shared between cores for example.  See  http://www.arm.com/Cortex-A7-chip-diagram-LG.png.  It wouldn't surprise me if the registers are not part of the shared part either.

Comment: @Andrew Tomazos: one per core. Any particular reason you're not using perf instead, which deals with all of these synchronization issues for you?

Comment: @unixsmurf: The end goal is to get a nanosecond timing source similar to what is described here for the Raspberry Pi 1: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/794.  I'll try building linux/tools/perf and see if that works, thanks.

Comment: @unixsmurf: Ok I've built and run `perf` successfully.  How do I read the cycle count register using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is to enable User level access of the counter. You have not enabled the counter as such. In addition to enabling access you have to program 31st bit (C-bit) of PMCNTENSET to enable counting. This along with your on_each_cpu() changes should enable the functionality you are looking for.

A word of caution: your measurements will be messed up, if a process migrates to a different core between CCNT reads.

Comment: Thanks - BTW with regard to your caution: `taskset -c k P` locks the program `P` onto core `k`.

Comment: That is a good way to solve it for single threaded applications.

Comment: For multithreaded programs, `sched_setaffinity` can set the core per thread.

Comment: I usually like to leave threading to the scheduler and then measure execution times. Overriding the scheduling priorities might not mimic the actual system in terms of available CPU bandwidth and Cache pressures. Eg. on an ARM V7 kernel I have worked on, Core 0 gets all the peripheral interrupts and in turn distributes it to other cores. So Core - 0  might be more loaded. But given that you are counting CPU cycles only cache pressures should affect your final measurement and it might be Ok for the use case you are targeting.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the working solution for posterity:

The kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static void enable_ccnt_read(void* data)
{
  // PMUSERENR = 1
  asm volatile ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" :: "r"(1));

  // PMCR.E (bit 0) = 1
  asm volatile ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0" :: "r"(1));

  // PMCNTENSET.C (bit 31) = 1
  asm volatile ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 1" :: "r"(1 << 31));
}

int init_module()
{
  on_each_cpu(enable_ccnt_read, NULL, 1);
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module()
{
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

The client program:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned ccnt_read ()
{

  volatile unsigned cc;
  asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r" (cc));
  return cc;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << ccnt_read() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb` v2.11 didn't like the `mcr` instructions: the kernel oopsed with invalid instruction. Maybe they are not implemented / not valid for that board? It is also worth nothing that this provides another way for userland to DoS the board: https://blog.regehr.org/archives/794#comment-4891

Comment: I am just curious, what will happen if I call the client program from 2 threads at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I am running this chip in simulation, and found a further problem to those described above. The performance counter must be reset when it is enabled, otherwise asserts are generated from the undefined values. This means that the PMCR register should be set as follows:

```
// PMCR.E (bit 0) = 1, PMCR.C (bit 2) = 1
asm volatile ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0" :: "r"(5));
```

Comment: Actually it was a Cortex R7 but fortunately the procedure appears to be the same.